# Assymptotics of a Selberg type integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, selberg-class, elliptic-integrals

Does any one know some references/ ideas on how to study the assymptotics as $N$ goes to $\infty$ of the following Selberg type integral

$$\int _{\mathbb R^N} e^{-|x|^2}\ \prod_{1\le i<j\le N} \sinh(|x_i - x_j|) dx$$